# How to fetch an artifact file from previous successful build?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I am working on creatting a rollback strategy in Gitlab CI.  For that I want to fetch the artifact file image_version.txt from previous successful build job.  Can someone please share how to do that.  We are using Gitlab [environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/#create-a-static-environment) feature.  So the goal is the fetch last successful pipeline from a Gitlab enviroment and the fetch this image_version.txt from a particular job(let's say create-image).

Secondly, I would like to know if I can use the Gitlab [caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html) feature for this.  Can I cache the image_version.txt in one job in a pipeline and use that in the rollback job in the current/new pipeline ?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the easiest way to achieve what you want is to use Gitlab generic package feature to [publish a package file](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/#publish-a-package-file).

You can upload any type of file under custom path where CI variables can be used like :

```
curl --header "JOB-TOKEN:$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --upload-file image_version.txt "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/generic/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_ENVIRONMENT/latest/image_version.txt"
```

API is also available to download package from jobs :

```
curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/generic/$CI_PROJECT_NAME/$CI_ENVIRONMENT/latest/image_version.txt" --output image_version.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question:

Generally the "cache" is used to have the dependencies or libraries stuff, which is going to be used in the job, however if you can use "cache".

While using "cache" one thing should be kept in mind though, that you should be using the same Runner in the subsequent job where you want to use the stuff from "cache", in a different runner you won't be getting the stuff you have stored, as each runner used to have it's own cache for the obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, sadly it took me a couple of hours to realize this but once I deleted the `artifacts: paths: ...` from the release stage then everything worked otherwise my wide guess would be that the runner was searching for the file that was to be uploaded in the "artifacts" and not finding it. I have no time to investigate and confirm the root cause so I ma just sharing what solved the problem for my case.

```
 deploy-artifacts:
      stage: deploy 
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - ${ARTIFACTS_DIR}/    
      script:
        - dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ./${ARTIFACTS_DIR}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.${GitVersion_LegacySemVer}

release:
  stage: release    
  script:
    - |
      7z a -y ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.${GitVersion_LegacySemVer}.zip ./${ARTIFACTS_DIR}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.${GitVersion_LegacySemVer}
      ls
      curl --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" \
      --upload-file ${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.${GitVersion_LegacySemVer}.zip \
      ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/${GitVersion_LegacySemVer}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}.${GitVersion_LegacySemVer}.zip
```